# Not able to show FLV video in Asp.net 4.0

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a flv video in video folder which i need to show in page. i have used object tag to show video, but its not showing anything. code which i have tried.

```
              <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0"
                    width="500" height="400" id="Untitled-1" align="middle">
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                    <param name="movie" value="../Video/Shortcut.flv" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#aaaaaa" />
                    <embed src="progressive2.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="500" height="400"
                        name="Untitled-1" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
                </object>
```

Comment: try `<video` tag.. you can aslo use **video.js** for that..

Comment: @Sac i think video tag is for HTML5 is it work on lower version.

Comment: use video.js for lower version.. check this site http://www.videojs.com/

Comment: you can also use image tag i.e <img... and set source to it and set height and width.